# SwiftUI Form Picker options are not selecting

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-picker

Why can't I select items from this picker view? The difference here is my selection array consist two different Structs('CustomOptionOne' and 'CustomOptionTwo') that conforms to the same protocol 'PickerOption'. The compiler gives me two errors,

> Type 'any PickerOption' cannot conform to 'Hashable'

> Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to
> 'AccessibilityRotorContent'

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protocol PickerOption: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var name: String { get set }
    var description: String { get set }
    var id: String { get }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    //I know it's this line, but my array will consist of any object that conforms to PickerOption protocol
    private static var exampleStructs: [any PickerOption] = [
        CustomOptionOne(name: "Example 1", description: "Example Name 1", id: "5"),
        CustomOptionOne(name: "Example 2", description: "Example Name 2", id: "6"),
        CustomOptionTwo(name: "Example 3", description: "Example Name 3", id: "7"),
        CustomOptionTwo(name: "Example 4", description: "Example Name 4", id: "8")
    ]
    
    private struct CustomOptionOne: Hashable, Identifiable, PickerOption {
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var id: String
    }
    
    private struct CustomOptionTwo: Hashable, Identifiable, PickerOption {
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var id: String
    }
    
    @State private var selectedStruct: any PickerOption = CustomOptionOne(name: "Example Name", description: "Example Description", id: "9")
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Selected Struct")) {
                    Text(selectedStruct.name)
                    Text(selectedStruct.description)
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Picker")) {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedStruct, label: Text(selectedStruct.name), content: {
                        ForEach(MyView.exampleStructs, id: \.id) { exampleStruct in
                            Text(exampleStruct.name).tag(exampleStruct)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked many answers including this [swift picker not selecting item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997025/swift-picker-not-selecting-item) and none of them are answering my use case scenario.

Comment: The type of the value you're passing to `tag` should match the type of the selection property. So you need to pass `exampleStruct` instead of `exampleStruct.id`. Does this answer your question? [swift picker not selecting item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997025/swift-picker-not-selecting-item)

Comment: Passing 'exampleStruct' gives this compile error `Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'`

Comment: An id isn’t a strict/object, the tag type needs to match the selection type

Comment: @loremipsum check my updated question, still it doesn't work.

Comment: You are better off using the id instead of the struct but SwiftUI is known for not working with existentials, so you might need to force ID to be a String with a typealias or my defining in the protocol

Comment: @loremipsum do you mind giving me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `Picker` the `tag` and the `selection` must be of the exact same type your specific example adds an additional layer of complexity because you are trying to use existentials (`any`) with SwiftUI.

So the simplest solution is to use the `ID` for both the `selection` and the `tag` but first you have to restrict the `ID` which comes from `Identifiable` to a specific type so you can match that for the `Picker`

```
protocol PickerOption: Hashable, Identifiable where ID == String {
    var name: String { get set }
    var description: String { get set }
    var id: String { get }
}
```

Then change the property to use a `String`

```
@State private var selectedStructId: String? = nil
```

Then change the `tag` to match the `selectedStructId`

```
Text(exampleStruct.name).tag(exampleStruct.id as String?)
```

The whole thing put together will look something like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    //I know it's this line, but my array will consist of any object that conforms to PickerOption protocol
    private static var exampleStructs: [any PickerOption] = [
        CustomOptionOne(name: "Example 1", description: "Example Name 1", id: "5"),
        CustomOptionOne(name: "Example 2", description: "Example Name 2", id: "6"),
        CustomOptionTwo(name: "Example 3", description: "Example Name 3", id: "7"),
        CustomOptionTwo(name: "Example 4", description: "Example Name 4", id: "8")
    ]
    
    private struct CustomOptionOne: PickerOption {
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var id: String
    }
    
    private struct CustomOptionTwo: PickerOption {
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var id: String
    }
    
    @State private var selectedStructId: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                if let selectedStructId, let selectedStruct = ContentView.exampleStructs.filter({ o in
                    o.id == selectedStructId
                }).first{ //Find the selected selected struct
                    Section(header: Text("Selected Struct")) {
                        Text(selectedStruct.name)
                        Text(selectedStruct.description)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Picker")) {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedStructId, label: Text(""), content: {
                        Text("Select an object.")
                        ForEach(ContentView.exampleStructs, id: \.id) { exampleStruct in
                            Text(exampleStruct.name).tag(exampleStruct.id as String?)

                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this isn't ideal but existentials are an uphill battle with SwiftUI.

Comment: As you have acknowledged, this is not an ideal solution. I was hoping to obtain the selected object without performing a lookup from the source array. However, I understand that we currently have no other solution with existentials. I'll accept this answer as it does resolve the original problem to some extent. Thanks for your effort.